# join dataframe based on values in other dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Here are two dataframes as follows

```
dataframe1:

column1   column2     value

abc       123abc      100

xyz       123abc      150

789       123abc      120

All       123abc      101
```

```
dataframe2:

level1   level2   level3

123      szx      abc

456      xyz      12sdd

789     jgvfg     hjghjg

912     dsg       All

412     All       grfg
```

The value in column1 may exist in level2 or level3 column of other data frame or in level1 also I need the level1 value for values in column1

```
Note: There may be All in the column1 of dataframe1 which has may values say 912,412 of level1 in other dataframe then those values are need to be there in Finaldataframe as follows
```

```
Finaldataframe:

newcolumn   column2   value

123         123abc    100

456         123abc    150

789         123abc    120

912         123abc    101

412         123abc    101
```

I want the output  as of Finaldataframe
So column1 can exists in either level2 or level3 and it sholud return the corresponding level1 column into newcolumn

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way to do it

```
# create a dictionary with the level1 and level2 of DF2 being the keys, 
# and level1 as a value by melting the DF2
d=df2.melt(id_vars='level1').set_index('value')['level1'].to_dict()
```

```
# Update using mask
# using mask, update the value of column1 where the map is not null

df1['column1']=df1['column1'].mask(df1['column1'].map(d) .notna(), df1['column1'].map(d)  )
df1
```

```
# OR using LOC  

df1.loc[df1['column1'].map(d).notna(), 'column1'] =df1['column1'].map(d)
df1
```

```
column1     column2     value
0   123.0   123abc  100
1   456.0   123xyz  150
2   789     hjgi    120
```